# How to know when trade agreements expire?

Tags: civilization-6

Where can I find when trade agreements expire?

I have an alliance and want to know how many turns until it expires. But of course this question refers to all agreements which have a turn limit.

Comment: While Civ6 seems more polished than pretty much any other initial release of civ I can think of, a few quality of life fixes like this will hopefully be coming in a patch soon.

Comment: Another little trick is that AI usually come back to you asking for the same stuff, kind of like a renewal which means it is ending next turn. I recommend removing an item and asking them what makes the deal work again as things can be worth more after 30 turns have passed. - Also in general it's 30 turns, same as the GPT trade length

Answer (score 2):

For deals involving gold, hover over the gold info in the top bar:
[image: gold per turn]

For luxuries, view the resources report:
[image: resource report]

For alliances, the alliances tab with that leader will display the turns remaining:
[image: alliances tab]

Comment: AFAIK the gold info in the top bar only lists income and expenses, but doesn't list the exipry date.

Comment: @Flater I've added a screenshot showing how the gold info displays turns remaining for gold from deals

Answer (score 0):

Put one gold per turn on either side of any agreement you want to keep track of. Not perfect but should help.

Better than that would be to write down on a notepad (physical or on screen) what trades to renew and on what turn. Hopefully there will be a trade log in game eventually...